# How can a Vue CLI plugin transpile javascript code in a vue.js project?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have a question: when i use vue cli babel plugin in vue.js project(@vue/cli-plugin-babel), where do i find the transpiled code? which folder? I can't find it.

```
For example:

If i have this javascript statement: 

 **- `import x from 'file1.js';`**

it will be transpiled to: 

 **- `var x = require('file1.js');`**

right? is it correct?
```

babel.config.js content:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it is what you are looking for but running `npm run build` will create a dist folder with the compiled javascript.

You can also have a dev build by adding the flag `npm run build -- --mode=development`

Comment: I have seen but i don't find the code converted to ES5